# How can I extract working files (in the form of graphics) from these MZP executables?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, executable, decompress, game-hacking

There's a 1999 PC/Mac game that I'm hoping to extract assets from. All game data appears to be stored in various files with the extension `.rsc`. I've been able to extract all the game's audio from the files, using tools such as Ravioli Explorer and Dragon Unpacker.

Here's where things get weird: Despite the files all ending in `.rsc`, changing the extension to `.exe` and opening it with various executable disassemblers (such as IDA) reveals that the files are in fact Pascal DOS executables  that match the New Executable (NE) Windows file format.

No idea why that's the case, and I have no idea what I can do with that information. I can't make heads or tails of the raw executable data, and I have no idea if it's even possible to extract working files from them. I know pretty much nothing about this topic, so help would be greatly appreciated.

I'll link a few of the files in question. If anyone wants to take a look at them and take a crack at it, I would be very grateful: [RR2G.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i51Bp3iPKF9xIdfsaZV4m2CRPE8p6RWs/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Did you already try opening the NE executables with a 16-bit resource editor?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Yeah, eXeScope was one of the programs I was able to open the files with.